# RAM usage with Win 7 32 PAE patched

Tags: windows-7, ram, 32-bit

I have to use Windows 7 32 bit in a computer, which I need to use a software which just works with this operating system unfortunately.

I have 8GB RAM installed I applied the patch developed by Unawave to let the OS see all the RAM installed. This is the link of the patch:

http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/32-bit-ram-barrier.html?lang=EN

However, I was also told that Windows 7 32 bit limits the usage of RAM for each application at 2 GB. Does this patch remove also this limit? In case it doesn't, do you know a way to get rid of this limit and to use at least 4GB for application, which I think it's the maximum possible for a 32 OS (as 2^32=4GB)?

Thanks a lot for letting me know.

E.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Be aware that there is a reasonable chance that the patch will cause your computer to bluescreen or otherwise misbehave, because it may be incompatible with your device drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a maximum of 3GB per process when you run this command `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072` and if the application supports the [IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) flag. *Nathan C* posted you a tool which sets the flag.